# menu key triggers mousedown event listener

Tags: javascript, mousedown

I've been working on my custom event listeners, when I faced this issue.
When I press the menu key , the mousedown event triggers on page position

```
offsetX: 1
offsetY: 1
```

, and the context menu appears on that position. BTW this is not my problem, because if I prevent the default contextmenu event, the mousedown event still triggers.
Here is my code:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.entry').on('mousedown',function(){
 console.log('mousedown triggered');
    });
});
```

```html
   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html,body{
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      margin:0;
      }
      .entry{
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      }
    </style>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <script src='./test.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can't get rid of this strange behavior, even if I use native javascript methods.
Every suggestion or help would be appreciated!

Comment: The context menu key (which is not the same as the windows key) fakes a right click keypress.

Comment: Using your code and native code, I was unable to reproduce your error. I hit both the Windows key, and the context menu key, to no avail. This was tested in Chrome, what browser are you using? Are you certain that what you think is happening is actually happening?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. I meant context key, not windows. I've checked, it has a keycode of 93.
My user agent is:
`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36`

Comment: I can filter these events generated by menu ky, if I discard all mousedown event, which occurs at page [1,1] position. But I can't find better solution.